# How to prevent AdView from stealing touch events from other view in the same list item in Android?

Tags: android, listview, admob

When clicking a list item with an AdMob AdView, all touch events are stolen even if clicking outside the ad.  For example, if I use a list item layout like the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="hello world!"/>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />

</LinearLayout>
```

All touch events will not be passed to the list item or the list view event if I click the TextView.

My question is, how can I prevent this?

Note that all touch events are successfully passed on until the ad is loaded.

Comment: Got the exact same problem. Did you find a way around this?